# Getting the first 2 numbers from a value of 5 numbers and entered in a new column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, slice, pandas-groupby

I've been looking for hours for a solution to this problem:
I would like to sort a column consisting of 5 numbers (integers).
Then I want to use the first 2 numbers of this value to make a grouping.
then I want to Count that groupings.

Is there a simple way to do that?
I use that for counting:

```
print(worksheet['postalcolumn'].value_counts())
```

The postalcolumn is like that **74**660, **74**5667, **78**320, **71**345
I want a new column like that 74, 74, 78, 71

Comment: Thanks, it works so wonderful. I would not have come to the solution.

If I want to group the records with a rule / filter and save them to a new Excel file, how do I do that?

Here is the example:

'new col',   'counts'

74 ,       9646
71 ,       25
70 ,       8
75 ,       8
69 ,       4
76 ,       3

Rule: Make a new worksheet from the existing worksheet if: 'new col' - 'count'> = 200 The rest should be in another new worksheet.

Comment: I think you should look at df.groupby . However this is a different question. But you should find enough solutions in SO. Still if you don't find one, feel free to post a new question and we will certainly help. :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the dtype of the column to string and use a `str`slicer , You can use:

```
worksheet['new_col']=worksheet['postalcolumn'].astype(str).str[:2].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `worksheet['postalcolumn']` is of type `list`, you can do:

```
worksheet['new_col'] = [] # create an empty new column
for id in worksheet['postalcolumn']:
    first_two = int(str(id)[:2]) # take the first two digits
    worksheet['new_col'].append(first_two) # add the two digits to the new column
```